# How to render a Component to use data on props but not show it on REACT JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to render a component because I need some of te props that comes with it to show on screen, but I dont want to show the element itself.

I tried using:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {

    const [elementLenght, setElementLenght] = useState(0);
    const [showHideElement , setShowHideElement ] = useState(false);

return (
   <Fragment>
     {showHideElement && (<Element lenght={setElementLenght} />)}
     <h1>{elementLenght}</h1>
   </Fragment>

)

}

export default Admin
```

The Element Component has an array of objects whit lenght of 8.

I am using the "elementLengt" data prop on other Component. So I want to render the element to obtain that data but not show until "shoHideElement" comes to true.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to do this? If there is some data on `Element` that you need in a higher component, it seems natural that you would put the data there instead and pass it down.

Comment: I am using the Element Component in other parts of my app but the length prop comes from an API call. So I want to make just one API call , every time I render the Element component,  not make the same api call in the other Components that have the element component as child.